# Use Sonoff thermostat TH10 in one room to control a Sonoff Basic in another room

Tags: thermostat, home-automation

For those who are experienced with the Sonoff devices, I need to check the temperature in my living room using a Sonoff thermostat TH10, and when the temperature is above a chosen threshold, I would like to stop the water pumps which are in a different room, using a "slave" Sonoff basic device, remotely controlled by the TH10.

Is such a configuration possible?

Comment: yes, that's very possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure is, but the TH10/15 is not a thermostat, but rather a thermistor. And setup depends on how you plan to control them, IFTTT, ewelink, Google Home, Amazon Alexa.....

Best to check in those forums.